# MySQL reduce index size for huge table

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb, entity-attribute-value, mysql-5.6

For my online shop I've a table, that I'm using for search:

```
CREATE TABLE `store_search` (
  `term` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `content_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('keyword','tag') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'keyword',
  `random` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `saving` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`content_id`,`term`,`type`),
  UNIQUE KEY `saving` (`term`,`saving`,`random`,`content_id`,`type`),
  UNIQUE KEY `random` (`term`,`random`,`content_id`,`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

Products can be listed in two ways: in a random order (based on column `random`) or by discount (based on column `saving`). Tests in past showed, that using `UNIQUE` constraints for order is much more performant than using standard indexes in conjunction with `ORDER BY`. A query can look like:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT content_id FROM store_search USE INDEX (random) WHERE term LIKE 'shirt%' AND type='keyword' LIMIT 2000,100;
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | store_search | range | random        | random | 152     | NULL | 9870580 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
```

So I can prevent an `ORDER BY` clause (no filesort is done with this approach). `PRIMARY KEY` is used for self joins when searching for multiple terms:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT x.content_id
    -> FROM store_search x USE INDEX (saving)
    -> INNER JOIN store_search y ON x.content_id=y.content_id
    -> WHERE x.term LIKE 'shirt%' AND x.type='keyword' AND y.term LIKE 'blue%' AND y.type='keyword'
    -> LIMIT 0,100;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+---------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys         | key     | key_len | ref          | rows     | Extra                                     |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+---------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | x     | range | PRIMARY,saving,random | saving  | 152     | NULL         | 11449970 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | y     | ref   | PRIMARY,saving,random | PRIMARY | 4       | x.content_id |       20 | Using where; Using index; Distinct        |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+---------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
```

As I said, this solution is fine so far. My problem is now: this table is so huge at present (~500mio rows), that the indexes do not fit in memory anymore. This causes, that `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements are terribly slow. Data takes 23GB and indexes consume 32GB, so 55GB at all for this table. Testing is possible, but consumes a lot of time when copying this table, but has anyone an approach to reduce the index size?
I'd like to convert collation of string columns to `latin_1`, but can I consolidate some of the indexes?

Comment: Are the number of distinct values in the column **term** limited to a few or are they really free text?

Comment: These are really free text. Longer terms are limited to 50 chars.

Comment: Is there any limit to the number of records you practically need to present to the end-user? I mean, if you get 10000 matches, would you really need to make all of them available?

Comment: The shop has a stream, so more content is loaded via Ajax. Sure, one can limit the stream, to show a maximum of 10000 products. What's your approach?

Comment: Do you you often have queries that specify no condition on the type, meaning that the result set will have both types represented? This I ask to see if it would not give a gain, if you split the table in two, one per type, which would also make the total size on indexes smaller. In the cases where you still need both types, you could `union` (with a cost)

Comment: I ask about the limit to see if **random** could be omitted completely. Then the result set must be limited to a maximum to then be sorted by a run-time random order, which on limited sets would not cost too much.

Comment: Often the queries look like `((term LIKE 'shirt%' AND type='keyword') OR (term='shirt' AND type='tag'))`, but splitting makes self joins more complicated when there are multiple terms given in search request. When omitting `random` then products are sorted based on `content_id` or `term` which is nothing I want, there is less diversity in first 10k results then.

Comment: OK, I understand. Do you need 10 digits for this **random** column, or would something like 4 be sufficient?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94550/discussion-between-rabudde-and-trincot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`term LIKE 'shirt%'` is a **range lookup**.  `INDEX(term, ...)` will not get past `term` for filtering in order to get to `type` or other columns.

This, and other basic indexing principles are discussed in my [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

So...  `WHERE term LIKE 'shirt%' AND type='keyword'` begs for `INDEX(keyword, term)`.  And adding any further columns won't help in *filtering*.

However...  What you are depending on is **covering**.  This is where all the desired columns are in a single index.  In this case, the query can be performed in the index BTree without touching the Data BTree.  That is, adding extra columns *can* be beneficial.

There are **multiple things** going on in

```
SELECT  content_id
    FROM  store_search USE INDEX (random)
    WHERE  term LIKE 'shirt%'
      AND  type='keyword'
    LIMIT  2000,100; 
UNIQUE KEY `random` (`term`,`random`,`content_id`,`type`)
```

Here are some:

- The index is "covering".
- There is no `ORDER BY`, so the output is probably ordered first by `term` (assuming there might be more than one phrase beginning with 'shirt'), and only secondarily by `random`.  This is not quite what you wanted, but may happen to work.
- The `LIMIT` requires it scan 2000+100 rows of the index, then quit.  It will stop short if there are are not enough shirts.  This probably seemed "fast".
- `UNIQUE` is probably irrelevant, and wasteful for inserts.

**Next query** Let's dissect `SELECT DISTINCT x.content_id ...`.

- You have replaced "filesort" with similar (possibly faster) code for `DISTINCT`.  There may not be a net gain; time it.
- If there are 999 blue shirts, it will find all 999, then DISTINCTify them, then deliver 100 of them.
- Without an `ORDER BY`, you can't predict which 100 will be delivered.
- Since you are already collecting all 999, adding `ORDER BY RAND()` won't add much overhead.
- Do you really want 'blue-green' shirts to be returned, but not 'light blue'?  And what about 'dress%' picking up 'dress pants'?  Kinky.

**Bottom line**

- Replace the 3 indexes with just `PRIMARY KEY(type, term, content_id)`.  By reaching in via the PK, you effectively get "covering".
- Use `ORDER BY random` or `ORDER BY RAND()` -- see which works better for you.  (The latter is more random!)
- Rethink the wild card in `LIKE 'shirt%'`

The bottom-bottom-line is that EAV schema design sucks.  I discuss this [*further*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav).

Comment: To update this question: as I mentioned, query time was not that bad. I've tried much approaches with different indexes. Slow thing was updating the table. So we've decided to use Solr for retrieving content IDs that have to be displayed in stream and that is fine for now, as huge search_* tables are gone.

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be set to about 70% of _available_ RAM.